# When Bitcoin Segwit fork will completely over?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm wondering for how much time it will takes for The Bitcoin Network to complete **Segwit Forking**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

August 3rd 12:45 CET:

`"segwit": {
      "status": "started",
      "bit": 1,
      "startTime": 1479168000,
      "timeout": 1510704000,
      "since": 439488,
      "statistics": {
        "period": 2016,
        "threshold": 1916,
        "elapsed": 1053,
        "count": 1053,
        "possible": true
      }
    }`

Another 864 BIP141 segwit singling blocks are required to activate.
This will roughly take 864 * 10 minutes == ~6 days (IF each block signal BIP141/bit 1).

As you may see, there are certain variables you can't know for sure (singling, block times)